# How should merge 2 element of array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge 2 element in array in PHP how can i do that. Please any on tell me.

```
$arr = array('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');  // these is my input

//i want output like 

array('Hello World!','Beautiful Day!');
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The generic solution would be something like this:

```
$result = array_map(function($pair) {
    return join(' ', $pair);
}, array_chunk($arr, 2));
```

It joins together words in pairs, so 1st and 2nd, 3rd and 4th, etc.

Comment: array_chunk($arr, 2) what's these ? and $arr or it's replace with $a

Comment: @GunjanPatel [Splits an array into chunks](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: @GunjanPatel It creates an array of word pairs, so `[['Hello', 'World!'], ['Beautiful', 'Day!']]` which is then fed into `join()` to form the final array.

Comment: @Steve That's only the partial result of my answer; the `array_map()` turns it into the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Specific to that case, it'd be very simple:

```
$result = array($arr[0].' '.$arr[1], $arr[2].' '.$arr[3]);
```

A more general approach would be

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 2) {
    if (isset($arr[$i+1])) {
        $result[] = $arr[$i] . ' ' . $arr[$i+1];
    }
    else {
        $result[] = $arr[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a real answer, since it only solves the specific example test case.

Comment: I still not think it's a good solution, because it can easily index out of the array when it has an odd number of elements.

Comment: That's what the modulo operator is for. I agree, though, the `array_chunk` solutions are better.

Comment: I overlooked that part, my bad. A condition inside the loop might also be a solution and in that case the result won't be empty.

Comment: Done, now the result won't be empty with an odd number of elements.

Comment: +1 for proposing the simple pragmatic one-time-use approach for simplifying things for a new user.  ...but -1 for using a for loop in the next part.

Answer (score 1):

In case your array is not fixed to 4 elements

```
$arr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $v){
  if (($i++) % 2==0)
    $arr[]=$v.' ';
  else {
    $arr[count($arr)-1].=$v;
  }
}
```

Live: http://ideone.com/VUixMS

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you dont know the total number of elements, but do know they will always an even number (else you cant join the last element), you can simply iterate `$arr` in steps of 2:

```
$count = count($arr);
$out=[];
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i+=2;){
    $out[] = $arr[$i] . ' ' .$arr[$i+1];
}
var_dump($out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
$arr = array('Hello', 'World!', 'Beautiful', 'Day!');
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  if (($key % 2 == 0) && (isset($arr[$key + 1]))) {
    $result[] = $value . " " . $arr[$key + 1];
  }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: @Kzqai: Thank you for fixing the closing parentheses. :)

Answer (score 0):

A easy solution would be:

```
$new_arr=array($arr[0]." ".$arr[1], $arr[2]." ".$arr[3]);
```

Comment: Not a real answer, since it only solves the specific example test case.